# Solution to Neumann's problem using the Maximum principle

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Hi recently in my sourcebook of Partial differential equations I came up with the Maximum Principle and I was trying to solve some of the suggested problems, but I got stuck with this one:

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. 
Prove using the Maximum Principle that the Neumann's Problem:
$$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  -\Delta u= 0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \Omega,\\
  \partial_{\nu} u=0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \partial\Omega.
 \end{array}
\right.$$
only has constant solutions.

P.D. I'm quite unsure about how to proceed with this problem, but at first I had the idea to use Hopf's Lemma to prove that the maximum is reached on the interior. This is the Lemma:
Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, and let $u \in C^{2}(U)\bigcap C(\overline{U})$ such that $\Delta u \geq 0 $ in $U$ and let $x_{0}\in\partial U$ such that $u(x)\geq u(x_{0})$ for all $x\in U$. Then the following is true: $\partial_{\nu}u(x_{0})<0$.
The problem that I have is that I'm not sure how to prove the hypothesis of this lemma for the problem that I have, as there is nothing told about $u$. Also, proving that the maximum is reached on the interior is enough? Or do I need something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline \Omega)$ solve the PDE and let $M= \max_{\overline \Omega} u$. Consider the set $\{u=M\}:=\{x\in \overline \Omega \text{ s.t. } u=M\}$. By the extreme value theorem, $\{u=M\} $ is non-empty. We claim that $$\{u=M\} \cap \Omega \neq \varnothing. \tag{$\ast$}$$ Suppose that, for the sake of contradiction, this is not the case. Then $\{u=M\} \subset \partial \Omega$ and so $u(x)<\max_{\overline \Omega} u$ for all $x\in \Omega$ and there exists $x_0\in \partial \Omega$ such that $u(x_0)=\max_{\overline \Omega} u$. But then Hopf's lemma, implies that $\partial_\nu u(x_0)<0$ which contradictions the Neumann boundary condition. Thus, we have proven $(\ast)$.

But this implies that there exists $x_0\in \Omega$ such that $u(x_0)=\max_{\overline \Omega} u$ so, by the strong maximum principle, $u$ is a constant.