# How to prove the uniqueness and stability of solution to Poisson equation using the maximum principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

I came across this problem in an exam. Given a Poisson equation on a bounded region $\Omega$,

$$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=f& u\in\Omega\\
\alpha u+\beta\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g&u\in\partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$

To prove that the solution is unique, I usually use the energy method (by intergrating and applying Green formula) since it is easy to transform the boundary differentiation into other forms. But in the exam, I was asked to use the maximum principle. [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467931/solution-to-neumanns-problem-using-the-maximum-principle) provided a way to resolve Neumann's BC using Hopf's lemma, but what about Robin/Mixed BC, there exists a plain term $\alpha u$ I don't know how to handle.

Could someone please help me?